# Ansible VMWare Expand Disk

Tags: ansible

What is Expected:

The playbook  will gather facts get the current drive space for a virtual machine and then add 30% to the disk.  It will then power down the VM and increase the drive by the 30% and boot it back up.  Once powered up ansible should then run the PowerShell script to expand the drive to 100% capacity.   This is what is expected.

What's happening is it fails at the PowerShell side of things.

```yaml
  - name: Disk extension
    win_partition:
      state: present
      partition_size: -1
      disk_number: 0
      partition_number: 2
```

This works to expand in vmware, I just need some help getting the aforementioned working in my code.  Hope that is understandable.

```yaml
---
- name: vm disk expansion
  hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
  - name: Get all disks from existing VM
    vmware_guest_disk_info:
      validate_certs: False
      datacenter: '{{ data_center }}'
      name: '{{ vm_name  }}'
    register: existing_disk

  - name: Get Backing datastore for desired disk id
    set_fact:
      disk_zero_datastore: "{{ item.value.backing_datastore }}"
    with_dict: "{{ existing_disk.guest_disk_info }}"
    when: item.key == '0'
  
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ disk_zero_datastore }}"
    when: disk_zero_datastore is defined

  - name: Get scsi controller type
    set_fact:
      scsi_type: "{{ item.value.controller_type }}"
    with_dict: "{{ existing_disk.guest_disk_info }}"
    when: item.key == '0'

  - debug:
      msg: '{{ scsi_type }}'
    when: scsi_type is defined


  - name: Get Unit Number
    set_fact:
      unit_number: "{{ item.value.unit_number }}"
    with_dict: "{{ existing_disk.guest_disk_info }}"
    when: item.key == '0'

  - debug:
      msg: '{{ unit_number }}'
    when: unit_number is defined


  - name: Get Disk + 30%
    set_fact:
      disc_size: "{{ item.value.capacity_in_kb|int *13/10| round(2, 'floor')|int }}"
    with_dict: "{{ existing_disk.guest_disk_info }}"
    when: item.key == '0'
  
  - debug:
      msg: '{{ disc_size }}'
    when: disc_size is defined

  - name: Connect to VMWare and shutdown guest
    community.vmware.vmware_guest:
      validate_certs: no
      datacenter: "{{ data_center }}"
      name: "{{ vm_name }}"
      state: shutdownguest
    delegate_to: localhost
    failed_when: vm_shutdown.instance.hw_power_status != 'poweredOff' and vm_shutdown.changed == false
    register: vm_shutdown

  - name: Wait 15 seconds
    ansible.builtin.pause:
      seconds: 15

  - name: Connect to VMWare and resize disk on VM
    community.vmware.vmware_guest_disk:
      validate_certs: no
      datacenter: "{{ data_center }}"
      name: "{{ vm_name }}"
      disk:
        - size_kb: "{{ disc_size|int }}"
          state: present
          unit_number: "{{ unit_number }}"
          scsi_controller: 0
          scsi_type: "{{ scsi_type }}"
    delegate_to: localhost
    register: disk_facts

  - name: Connect to VMWare and boot up guest
    community.vmware.vmware_guest:
      validate_certs: no
      name: "{{ vm_name }}"
      state: poweredon
    delegate_to: localhost
#    register: disk_facts

  - name: Wait 300 seconds, but only start checking after 15 seconds
    wait_for_connection:
      delay: 15
      timeout: 300
  
  - name: Extend disk to 100%
```

Comment: What is the part of the code you get a problem with? What is the result you get? What is the one you expect instead? Please read [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and thought I would post for others:

Use: AWX Operator / AKA Ansible Tower
Code:

```
---
- name: vm disk expansion
  hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
  - name: Get all disks from existing VM
    vmware_guest_disk_info:
      validate_certs: False
      datacenter: '{{ data_center }}'
      name: '{{ vm_name  }}'
    register: existing_disk

  - name: Get Backing datastore for desired disk id
    set_fact:
      disk_zero_datastore: "{{ item.value.backing_datastore }}"
    with_dict: "{{ existing_disk.guest_disk_info }}"
    when: item.key == '0'
  
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ disk_zero_datastore }}"
    when: disk_zero_datastore is defined

  - name: Get scsi controller type
    set_fact:
      scsi_type: "{{ item.value.controller_type }}"
    with_dict: "{{ existing_disk.guest_disk_info }}"
    when: item.key == '0'

  - debug:
      msg: '{{ scsi_type }}'
    when: scsi_type is defined


  - name: Get Unit Number
    set_fact:
      unit_number: "{{ item.value.unit_number }}"
    with_dict: "{{ existing_disk.guest_disk_info }}"
    when: item.key == '0'

  - debug:
      msg: '{{ unit_number }}'
    when: unit_number is defined


  - name: Get Disk + 30%
    set_fact:
      disc_size: "{{ item.value.capacity_in_kb|int *13/10| round(2, 'floor')|int }}"
    with_dict: "{{ existing_disk.guest_disk_info }}"
    when: item.key == '0'
  
  - debug:
      msg: '{{ disc_size }}'
    when: disc_size is defined

  - name: Connect to VMWare and shutdown guest
    community.vmware.vmware_guest:
      validate_certs: no
      datacenter: "{{ data_center }}"
      name: "{{ vm_name }}"
      state: shutdownguest
    delegate_to: localhost
    failed_when: vm_shutdown.instance.hw_power_status != 'poweredOff' and vm_shutdown.changed == false
    register: vm_shutdown

  - name: Wait 300 seconds, but only start checking after 15 seconds
    wait_for_connection:
      delay: 15
      timeout: 300

  - name: Connect to VMWare and resize disk on VM
    community.vmware.vmware_guest_disk:
      validate_certs: no
      datacenter: "{{ data_center }}"
      name: "{{ vm_name }}"
      disk:
        - size_kb: "{{ disc_size|int }}"
          state: present
          unit_number: "{{ unit_number }}"
          scsi_controller: 0
          scsi_type: "{{ scsi_type }}"
    delegate_to: localhost
    register: disk_facts

  - name: Connect to VMWare and boot up guest
    community.vmware.vmware_guest:
      validate_certs: no
      name: "{{ vm_name }}"
      state: poweredon
    delegate_to: localhost
#    register: disk_facts
  
  - name: Wait 300 seconds, but only start checking after 30 seconds
    wait_for_connection:
      delay: 30
      timeout: 300
  
  
  - name: Connect to windows host and expand the drive
    ansible.windows.win_powershell:
      script: |
        # Variable specifying the drive you want to extend
        $drive_letter = "C"

        # Script to get the partition sizes and then resize the volume
        $size = (Get-PartitionSupportedSize -DriveLetter $drive_letter)
        Resize-Partition -DriveLetter $drive_letter -Size $size.SizeMax
```

The real missing piece was:

On the host side: localhost  On the inventory placing these extra variables.   Not sure why I forgot this as all my inventories which deal with windows based machines in Ansible Tower have these:

```
---
ansible_user: AVH_NT\svc_account
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_port: 5985
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
ansible_winrm_transport: ntlm
ansible_become_method: runas
```

Oh and one other thing, adding more time for the machine to boot up, the code was trying to run before the machine was fully up.

```
- name: Wait 300 seconds, but only start checking after 30 seconds
    wait_for_connection:
      delay: 30
      timeout: 300
```

Comment: Sorry more definition: